# How do I restart the newer ALT+TAB task switcher in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, task-switching

My task switcher seems to have crashed and now I can only get the task switcher from Windows XP. How do I restart the newer task switcher? I'm sure it will work after I restart, but I don't want to do that right now.

[image: task switcher]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt+Tab is managed by [**CSRS (Client/Server Runtime Subsystem)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem). Restarting the Explorer (*explorer.exe*) process should fix the problem.

Comment: Or just reboot. That fixes many issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Explorer and it started working again. It crashed earlier and restarted itself, so I don't know why it broke before.